# PrincipalPermission attribute on Service contract

Tags: .net, wcf

Is there a technical reason why a PrincipalPermission can't be placed on a service contract interface?  It only works on the class implementing the contract or directly on the class methods.

This doesn't work.

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IMyService
{
    [PrincipalPermission(SecurityAction.Demand, Role="Admin")]
    [OperationContract]
    void MyFunction(string str);
}
```

But it works if I place the attribute on the matching method in the class implementing IMyService.

Comment: I just spent 2 hours debugging this...  Could not for the life of me understand my my `PrincipalPermissionAttribute` settings were getting ignored...  I didn't even know what to ask, was it my Ninject DI container, was it the fact I'm self hosting, was it because i am using custom `MembershipProvider`/`RoleProvider`, was it something mis-wired in the app config?  Thanks for asking the right question for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The role is checked at runtime, using the attributes put on the implementing method, not the attributes put on the interface the method implements. More generally in .NET there is not direct relation between custom attributes put on a method and custom attributes put on the corresponding interface method, if any.

Comment: I guess what I'm asking is, is there a technical reason why PrincipalPermission should not be declared on a service contract or is that an oversight in the framework?  I could write my own authorization attribute but since PP doesn't work on interfaces I was wondering if there was a good reason for that.

Comment: The reason is there is no technical relation in .NET between attributes on methods of an interfaces and attributes on the corresponding methods in classes implementing these interfaces. I don't know how to say it differently.

Comment: Oh well, had to do it myself with a custom IOperationInvoker that checks the roles of Thread.CurrentPrincipal. My custom invoker was attached using an IOperationBehavior and an Attribute on the interface.

Answer (score 1):

I know the post is old in attempt to provide a concrete answer to the OPs question the reason lies in the difference between an interface and a class.

Think about it; 
An interface is a description of an implementation it is not a behavior of an implementation. 
 *An interface just describes the class methods and events etc..*

[*Or as Microsoft says it:*](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms229013(v=vs.100).aspx)

> An interface defines the signatures for a set of members that
>   implementers must provide. Interfaces cannot provide **implementation
>   details** ~ *(behavior)* for the members.

*A class that inherits an interface provides the behavior of those methods and events. - that is to say implements the [behavior ~ functionality] of the interface*

**So then why the Interface:**

*Do define an interface if you need to provide a polymorphic hierarchy of value types.*

*Consider defining interfaces to achieve an effect similar to that of multiple inheritance.*

https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms229013(v=vs.100).aspx

Hope this helps someone else understand.